# Handlebars variable not accessible inside each block

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

I have this Handlebars (Express.js) code:

```
{{page.path}}
{{#each navigation}}
  {{page.path}}
{{/each}}
```

The problem is that `page.path` is accessible outside of `#each` block, but it is not accessible inside that block's scope. How do I make it work inside `#each` block?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found solution, it can be accessed by using `../` Up level in unix-like path syntax:

```
{{#each navigation}}
  {{../page.path}}
{{/each}}
```